# Pull data from mysql that was entered today

Tags: php, mysql

Am I not seeing something obvious here, can't seem to get this to work...

```
if (($_GET['date']=='today'))
{ 
    $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today'));     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE (contacttype = 'Buyer' OR "
           . "contacttype = 'Seller' OR contacttype = 'Buyer / Seller' OR "
           . "contacttype = 'Investor') AND date = '$today' ORDER BY date DESC";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can either change `strtotime('today')` to `time()`, or just remove the 2nd parameter to `date()`. Either or is better in this case, and will return the same values.

Comment: thanks, I changed it to time() and still doesn't work...weird

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using `contacttype IN('Buyer', 'Seller', 'Buyer / Seller', 'Investor')`

Comment: var_dump( $_GET ); var_dump( $query ); does the query work?  what errors are you getting?

Comment: no errors marabutt...just nothing. i also have "this week" and "last week" and they both work fine...

Comment: Almost all answers here seems to be fine, how do you get that `$_GET['date']=='today'`? Let's start from the top.

Comment: can you paste the result from var_dump( $_GET ); var_dump( $query );?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use PHP to tell MySQL what today is, it already knows!

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE (contacttype = 'Buyer' OR contacttype = 'Seller' OR contacttype = 'Buyer / Seller' OR contacttype = 'Investor') AND date = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY date DESC
```

will work, assuming all of the other conditions in your WHERE clause are correct. See MySQL's [date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and [now()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) reference.

Comment: this doesn't work either, i even pulled everything else out... `    if (($_GET['date'] == 'today'))
    {     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE date = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY date DESC";    }`

Comment: Try running this query on its own in a query window. If this query doesn't return anything, then it needs modification. If the query returns the data that you want, make sure $query is defined after your condition. I may need to see the code running the query and doing work on the result set to help you further.

Comment: After looking at your query again, you could actually rewrite it as follows: `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact IN ('Buyer','Seller','Buyer / Seller','Investor') AND date=DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY date DESC` which is quite a bit nicer.

Comment: check it out, the only one that doesn't work is Today...`    if (($_GET['date'] == 'today'))
    {     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE date = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY date DESC";
    }

    if (($_GET['date'] == 'thisweek'))
    {   
    $thisweek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this sunday'));     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE (contacttype = 'Buyer' OR contacttype = 'Seller' OR contacttype = 'Buyer / Seller' OR contacttype = 'Investor') AND date BETWEEN '$thisweek' AND '$thisweek' + INTERVAL 7 DAY ORDER BY date DESC"; 
    }`

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that perhaps your $query variable is getting overwritten before it's executed to something else, the query itself is broken and isn't returning anything, or you don't actually have any entries in the table for today. Try running the query by itself in a query window and see if it runs as expected. If it does, then the problem lies with your PHP code and not the query.

Comment: did it in a query window and it's returning 0 results...that is strange because I put 3 records in, one with yesterdays, todays and tomorrows date...any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you include your database dump on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
where DATE(dt) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: you sure there is not a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts
WHERE (contacttype = 'Buyer'
        OR contacttype = 'Seller'
        OR contacttype = 'Buyer / Seller'
        OR contacttype = 'Investor')
    AND DATE = CUR_DATE()
ORDER BY DATE DESC`
```